# How can I re-use my wordpress action hook functions as 'normal' functions

Tags: php, wordpress

I have an function action hook which collects subscriptions from our database. I want to use this so that I can display the subscriptions on the page, but I also want to use this function in another function that calculates the new subscription price. Is this possible?

My code looks somewhat like this

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_get_get_subs_with_type', 'get_subs_with_type' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_get_get_subs_with_type', 'get_subs_with_type' );

function get_subs_with_type($sub_type) {
    $subs = //get alot of info from database......
    echo $subs;
}
```

But I also want to use this function with a `return` statement instead of `echo` to be used in another function.

```
functon calc_subs(){
    $subs = get_subs_with_type();
    return $subs[1]->price + 1;
}
```

So can I use a function tied to an action hook as a 'normal' function as well? Or what should I do?

EDIT:

If there is no good way of doing this, I made a little hacky solution:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_get_get_subs_with_type', 'get_subs_with_type' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_get_get_subs_with_type', 'get_subs_with_type' );

function get_subs_with_type($sub_type) {
    $subs = get_sub_from_db()
    echo $subs;
}

function get_sub_from_db() {
    $subs = //get alot of info from database......
    return $subs;
}
```

Now I can use `get_sub_from_db()` in my other function as well.

```
functon calc_subs(){
    $subs = get_sub_from_db();
    return $subs[1]->price + 1;
}
```

What do you think of this?

Answer (score 1):

You can for example do something like:

```
/**
 * Returns bla bla bla
 * @return array 
 */
function get_subs_with_type($sub_type) {
    $subs = //get alot of info from database......
    return $subs;
}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_get_get_subs_with_type', function () {
    echo get_subs_with_type();
});
```

but remember that while using `anonymous` function you will not be able to remove this action with [remove_action](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_action).

Answer (score 0):

The solution you proposed, by creating two different function, one returning the database call & the other calling the first one looks quite good.

Don't forget to add a `wp_die();` function after you echoed all this information to the ajax handler. This is required to terminate any ajax call immediately and return a proper response.